# SwiftUI LazyVGrid with scroll view issue

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollview, lazyvgrid

The text "Bottom Text" is intended to occupy some space at the bottom. However, when using a LazyVGrid with a scroll view, the content ends up being rendered behind the bottom text, and the scrollable area appears to stretch beyond the screen.

How can this issue be resolved?

**Expected**

[image: Expected]

**Actual**

[image: Actual]

```
struct HFlexibleView<Content: View>: View {
    let triggerWidth: CGFloat
    let content: () -> Content
    ///If this is set true, the view will be rendered normally, insead of being arranged flexibly
    var disabled: Bool
    var maxmumWidth: CGFloat
    var columns: [GridItem] {
        [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: triggerWidth,
                            maximum: maxmumWidth))]
    }
    
    init(triggerWidth: CGFloat,
         maxmumWidth: CGFloat = .infinity,
         disabled: Bool = false,
         @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.triggerWidth = triggerWidth
        self.maxmumWidth = maxmumWidth
        self.disabled = disabled
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {

        if disabled {
            content()
        } else {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                    content()
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }

            }
        }
        
    }
}


struct FlexbibleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        VStack {
            HFlexibleView(triggerWidth: 500) {
                ScrollView {
                    ForEach(0...20, id: \.self) {_ in
                        Image(systemName: "keyboard")
                            .font(.system(size: 30))
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 50)
                            .background(Color.green)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                    }
                }
            }
            Text("Bottom Text")
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for `LazyVGrid` says: A container view that arranges its child views in a grid **that grows vertically**, creating items only as needed.

So you could use a specific size to constrain the `content` (i.e the `ScrollView`), such as:

```
 GeometryReader { geometry in
     LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
         content()
             .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: geometry.size.height)
     }
 }
```